# searching array of 'str' type in string file

Tags: python, string, excel, search, unicode

I am searching for text present in `non_int_ram_var` in `trial.txt`. `non_int_ram_var` takes data from an excel sheet which is basically unicode. So I type-cast it to `str` so that the `trial.txt` type will match with `non_int_ram_var`. But the control is not entering into `if var in line:`. I have cross-verified that `var` is present in one of the line of the text file. I might be making some mistake. Can anyone give me a suggestion?

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
import unicodedata
work_book= open_workbook("C:\\Users\\E542639\\Desktop\\non_sram_mem\\SEU_MBU_FINAL_VARIABLE_LIST.xls");

# reading xls file for non_int sram..............
non_int_ram_var = [] * 376
row=1

for sheet in work_book.sheets():
    if "Data" == sheet.name :
        print sheet.nrows, sheet.ncols
        while row < sheet.nrows:
            if "int_sram" != sheet.cell(row,5).value:
                if "file name only" != sheet.cell(row,7).value :
                    non_int_ram_var.append(str(sheet.cell(row,1).value))
            row=row + 1

# checking variable in mapfile.........

map_file = open("C:\\Users\\E542639\\Desktop\\non_sram_mem\\trial.txt", "r")
non_categorized = open("C:\\Users\\E542639\\Desktop\\non_sram_mem\\non_categorized.txt","w")

print "processing..."

for var in non_int_ram_var:
    while True:
        line = str.encode(map_file.readline())
        if not line: break

        if var in line:
            print "control here"
            non_categorized.writelines(line)  # write won't work

print 'done!!!'

map_file.close()
non_categorized.close()
```

==================================================================

after reading till end of the file in next iteration cursor was not coming to beginning of the file. which was my mistake. thanks poke, ur suggestion shown the way. this what i did now and working fine.

if not line:
            map_file.seek(0)
            break

Comment: will you please check what is the value of `line` and `var` before checking if condition ? and if you check `str` in `unicode` then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Python read the file into str object by default.

I think you could try

```
for line in map_file:
     if var in line:
        print "control here"
        ...
```

Comment: after reading till end of the file in next iteration cursor was not coming to beginning of the file. which was my mistake. thanks poke, ur suggestion shown the way. this what i did now and working fine.

if not line: map_file.seek(0) break